# Vuetify's fab button icon is not centered vertically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, material-design, vuetify.js

I can't get vuetify's fab button to be centered vertically.

Here is my usage, noting special out of the ordinary.

```
<v-btn 
    color="primary" 
    fab 
    small >
    <v-icon>print</v-icon>                  
</v-btn>
```

Here is my main.js file

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
import "material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";
import "typeface-roboto/index.css";
Vue.use(Vuetify);
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

this is the output

[image]

**I am using Vue 2.5.16 and Vuetify 1.1.3 versions**

*i.e I haven't added styles or any external other css*

---

**Update**: 
 i found a workaround by adding `height:auto` on `v-icon`

```
<v-icon style="height:auto;">print</v-icon>
```

but still it isn't a solution.

Comment: What version do you use? I prepared codepen with your btn but it works fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBWEpV?editors=1010

Comment: the Vuetify version is 1.1.3

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: @AnkitKumarOjha nope

Comment: are you using any sort of flex'

Comment: nope, but vuetify use flexbox. its kind of weird that when i try to spin up a new project with vuetify i don't see the problem.

Comment: I always have a choice of redoing with new installation of vue and vuetify but i wanted to understand the problem.

Comment: Was working great for me...then began to have this issue with no code or version changes...quite confused.  Re-ran `npm install` and it fixed the issue.

Comment: I too am experiencing this problem but I have noticed that it only appears in firefox, not chrome.

Comment: reproduce on [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com/)

Answer (score 12):

In my case it is because the order of CSS import

[FAB icon not centered vertically](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4001)

[Add information about load Google font before Vuetify css](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com/issues/353)

```
import "material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
```